# How to parse text file based on specific keywords in text file

Tags: java

I currently have a text file that I would like to parse into classes. However, I can't figure out why it isn't doing it properly. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

`

```
            case "1":
                try{
                    //Create file
                    File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/Olivia/Desktop/CIS331/products.txt");
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
                    //read data from file
                    while (scanner.hasNext()){
                        String type = scanner.nextLine();
                        //System.out.println(type);
                        if (type.equals( "PRODUCT")){
                            String pName= scanner.nextLine();
                            String pDescription = scanner.nextLine();
                            int pQuantity = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                            double pPrice = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                            boolean add = Product.addProduct(pName, pDescription, pQuantity, pPrice);
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (type.equals("AUTOMOBILE")){
                            String pName= scanner.nextLine();
                            String pDescription = scanner.nextLine();
                            int pQuantity = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                            double pPrice = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                            int y = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                            String mm = scanner.nextLine();
                            boolean add = Automobile.addAutomobile(pName, pDescription, pQuantity, pPrice, y, mm);
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (type.equals("VIDEO")){
                            String pName= scanner.nextLine();
                            String pDescription = scanner.nextLine();
                            int pQuantity = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                            double pPrice = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
                            String genre = scanner.nextLine();
                            String rate = scanner.nextLine();
                            int time = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                            String star = scan.nextLine();
                            boolean add= Video.addVideo(pName, pDescription, pQuantity, pPrice, type, rate, time, star);
                           break;
                        }}
                        System.out.println("File read successfully");                         
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error reading" + e.toString());
                }
                break;
```

`

.txt file :
[image: this is the input file]

Comment: You need to do a much better job of explaining what you expect to happen and what is actually happening and what you think is causing it. Are you getting errors? If so, what is it?

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like?  Also, seconded @PaulSamsotha, you haven't given us enough information about what is happening compared to what should.  You have given us one case from what I presume is a switch block.  What is case 1?  What other cases are there?  To make your code a lot less painful to look at and test, most of this logic should be extracted into smaller methods, e.g. when you have a video, invoke getMovieDetails(Scanner scanner) and use that method to get the rest of the video data and add the new video to your Video.